# Show hourly price on Stripe payment instead of deposit price

Tags: android, google-api, stripe-payments, payment, google-pay

For a rental company, we need to set up deferred payment.

When a user rents an item we must lock $25 on his credit card (a deposit).
He will be charged $1 per hour. If he returns his item within 5 hours, he will be charged $5. After 25 hours we consider the item lost and it is charged the full price $25.

At the time of the customer payment validation we should show a $1 bill (not a $25 bill).

We managed to implement this on Apple Pay with `pkdeferredpaymentsummaryitem`.

Do you have any idea how to implement this with Stripe Pay?

For the moment here is our code:

```java
public PaymentIntent createCapturePaymentIntent(String amount, String currency, String customerId,
  String paymentMethodId, String description) throws Exception {
  Map < String, Object > params = new HashMap < > ();
  params.put("amount", amount);
  params.put("currency", currency);
  params.put("customer", customerId);
  if (null != paymentMethodId) {
    params.put("payment_method", paymentMethodId);
  }
  params.put("description", description);
  //        params.put("confirm", "true");
  params.put("capture_method", "manual");
  LoggerHelper.mdc("stripe", "createCapturePaymentIntent body ==> {}", JacksonUtils.toJson(params));
  PaymentIntent paymentIntent = null;
  try {
    paymentIntent = PaymentIntent.create(params, requestOptions);
  } catch (CardException e) {
    LoggerHelper.mdc("stripe", "createCapturePaymentIntent error ==> {}: {}", e.getCode(), e.getMessage());
    String paymentIntentId = e.getStripeError().getPaymentIntent().getId();
    paymentIntent = PaymentIntent.retrieve(paymentIntentId, requestOptions);
  }
  LoggerHelper.mdc("stripe", "createCapturePaymentIntent result ==> {}", JSON.toJson(paymentIntent));
  return paymentIntent;
}
```

But the user is shown a $25 bill instead of a $1 one:

[image]

[Apple Pay Documentation: pkdeferredpaymentsummaryitem](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/passkit/pkdeferredpaymentsummaryitem)

---

Edit: Do you think creating a $1 payment with the option `setup_future_usage` set to `off_session` is a good idea to achieve our goal?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "he's shown a $25 bill instead of a $1 one"? Are you referring to a specific UI, or something else? From what I can see this is how you'd implement this in Stripe, by creating a Payment Intent with `capture_method: manual` and then capture the correct amount when the item is returned or the 25 hours is up.

Comment: @karbi on Apple Pay the user is shown a $1 payment even if the deferred payment total value is $25. We dont' want to show the full price at the time of the renting because it will scare customers. I've seen that we can maybe create a $1 payment and use `setup_future_usage` to `off_session` to capture the rest when the item is returned.

Comment: Since your customers agree to your certain terms and condition, your app UI can display $1 while in the background you'll deduct the full $25. This should solve it if stripe doesn't have the API method to do that.

Answer (score -1):

Since your customers agree to your certain terms and condition, your app UI can display $1 on the frontend and while in the background, you'll deduct the full $25. This should solve it if stripe doesn't have the API method to do that

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. But i'm not asking for the legal part of it, I'm trying to understand the best way to implement this programmatically.